Get type of an object according to its key/values
I have a group of objects with const values, and these objects should follow a specific type definition.
The problem is that when I assign a type on the object, no longer get autocomplete or type annotations for them.
type URLDefinition = {
  [key: Uppercase<string>]: string;
};

const General: URLDefinition = {
  BASE: "api/",
} as const;

const Search = {
  ACCOUNTS: "api/v1/accounts",
  lowerPath: "api/v1", // unable to enforce Uppercase strict
                       // typing, because lack of type definition
} as const;

console.log(General.WRONG); // won't throw error 
console.log(Search.WRONG); // throw error 

How can I have both an object type definition and autocomplete at the same time?

When you use a type annotation on a variable you get exact this type for the variable, so WRONG is a valid key for URLDefinition. Usually this leads to wider types. If you want your exact variable type but satisfying another type use satisfies:
Playground
const General= {
  BASE: "api/",
} as const satisfies URLDefinition;

